# MailKit.Security.SslHandshakeException when running as Windows Service

Tags: c#, email, mailkit, starttls

Sending Mails works perfectly fine for me when I run the exe, however deploying it as a Windows Service breaks it. I am using "smtp.gmail.com" as SMTP-Server.

```
            var email = new MimeMessage();
            email.From.Add(new MailboxAddress(name, loginmail));
            email.To.Add(new MailboxAddress(mailQueueDO.TargetMail));
            email.Subject = mailQueueDO.Subject;
            email.Body = new TextPart(TextFormat.Html) { Text = mailQueueDO.HTML };

            using var smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Connect(smtpserver, 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);
            smtp.Authenticate(loginmail, loginpassword);
            smtp.Send(email);
            smtp.Disconnect(true);
```

I can't wrap my head around why running this code manually by starting the exe would yield different results than running it as Windows Service.

The fixes specified in the [FAQ](https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/blob/master/FAQ.md#InvalidSslCertificate) did not work for me.

Comment: What suggestions did you actually try from the FAQ?

Comment: The detail **breaks it** does not help. What error/problem actually occurs?

Comment: MailKit.Security.SslHandshakeException: An error occurred while attempting to establish an SSL or TLS connection.    The server's SSL certificate could not be validated ...

I've attempted to modify the Port used to 465 and attempted all of the SecureSocketOptions. None of those options worked.

Since the code works while run in console, running it as service has to somehow change how SSL/TLS works.

Comment: If you use port 465, you need to change SecureSocketOptions.StartTls to SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect

Answer (score 3):

> MailKit.Security.SslHandshakeException: An error occurred while
> attempting to establish an SSL or TLS connection. The server's SSL
> certificate could not be validated

If the SMTP server's certificate is invalid, you have two choices. Fail the connection or ignore the certificate.

Two examples to demonstrate custom certificate validation.

**Example 1: Ignore server certificate errors:**

```
using System;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

using MimeKit;
using MailKit;
using MailKit.Security;
using MailKit.Net.Smtp;

namespace MailKit.Examples
{
    public static class SslCertificateValidationExample
    {
        public static void SendMessage (MimeMessage message)
        {
            using (var client = new SmtpClient ()) {
                // Set our custom SSL certificate validation callback.
                client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = MySslCertificateValidationCallback;

                // Connect
                smtp.Connect(smtpserver, 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);

                // Authenticate with our username and password.
                smtp.Authenticate(loginmail, loginpassword);

                // Send our message.
                client.Send (message);

                // Disconnect cleanly from the server.
                client.Disconnect (true);
            }
        }

        static bool MySslCertificateValidationCallback (object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**Example 2: Process everything.**

This example will not solve your problem but should help identify the problem with the server's certificate.

```
using System;
using System.Net.Security;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

using MimeKit;
using MailKit;
using MailKit.Security;
using MailKit.Net.Smtp;

namespace MailKit.Examples
{
    public static class SslCertificateValidationExample
    {
        public static void SendMessage (MimeMessage message)
        {
            using (var client = new SmtpClient ()) {
                // Set our custom SSL certificate validation callback.
                client.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = MySslCertificateValidationCallback;

                // Connect
                smtp.Connect(smtpserver, 587, SecureSocketOptions.StartTls);

                // Authenticate with our username and password.
                smtp.Authenticate(loginmail, loginpassword);

                // Send our message.
                client.Send (message);

                // Disconnect cleanly from the server.
                client.Disconnect (true);
            }
        }

        static bool MySslCertificateValidationCallback (object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
        {
            // If there are no errors, then everything went smoothly.
            if (sslPolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None)
                return true;

            // Note: MailKit will always pass the host name string as the `sender` argument.
            var host = (string) sender;

            if ((sslPolicyErrors & SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNotAvailable) != 0) {
                // This means that the remote certificate is unavailable. Notify the user and return false.
                Console.WriteLine ("The SSL certificate was not available for {0}", host);
                return false;
            }

            if ((sslPolicyErrors & SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateNameMismatch) != 0) {
                // This means that the server's SSL certificate did not match the host name that we are trying to connect to.
                var certificate2 = certificate as X509Certificate2;
                var cn = certificate2 != null ? certificate2.GetNameInfo (X509NameType.SimpleName, false) : certificate.Subject;

                Console.WriteLine ("The Common Name for the SSL certificate did not match {0}. Instead, it was {1}.", host, cn);
                return false;
            }

            // The only other errors left are chain errors.
            Console.WriteLine ("The SSL certificate for the server could not be validated for the following reasons:");

            // The first element's certificate will be the server's SSL certificate (and will match the `certificate` argument)
            // while the last element in the chain will typically either be the Root Certificate Authority's certificate -or- it
            // will be a non-authoritative self-signed certificate that the server admin created. 
            foreach (var element in chain.ChainElements) {
                // Each element in the chain will have its own status list. If the status list is empty, it means that the
                // certificate itself did not contain any errors.
                if (element.ChainElementStatus.Length == 0)
                    continue;

                Console.WriteLine ("\u2022 {0}", element.Certificate.Subject);
                foreach (var error in element.ChainElementStatus) {
                    // `error.StatusInformation` contains a human-readable error string while `error.Status` is the corresponding enum value.
                    Console.WriteLine ("\t\u2022 {0}", error.StatusInformation);
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```